# Setting Up a CI/CD Pipeline for An Angular 7 Application From Azure DevOps to AWS S3

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I am new to working with Angular 7 app, I am attempting to create a CI/CD pipeline to deploy to AWS S3 on a sample app,
but I get an error on CI build part when doing ng Build.

I am following this tutorial, and it doesnt explain how to tackle this error:
https://dzone.com/articles/setup-a-cicd-pipeline-for-spring-boot-application

Here is my solution and error:

CI:

[pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1NWr.png)

Error:
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vya0V.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8KIA.png)

How can I fix my pipeline so it doesn't fail on the ng build step.

Thank in advance

Tried to remove the package.json and pushed it to repo, and try running ng build didnt work. Works okay on my local environment

Also tried to add the install angular step before the build step, yet it fails.

Comment: which build agent pool are you using to run the pipeline?

Comment: @Sibtain Agent pool is Azure Pipeline and Azure Specefication is ubuntu-latest

Comment: I am assuming this is POC as you are deploying a sample app. Since this works on your local machine you can easily setup your local machine as a self-hosted build agent and run the pipeline on it.